# Explanation for speed of an electrical impulse

Tags: electricity, classical-electrodynamics

Our calculus book, Stewart,  has a problem where they claim that for a metal cable (inner radius $r$) encased in insulation (outer radius $R$), the speed of an electrical impulse is given by

$$v = - k \left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2 \ln \left(\frac{r}{R}\right)$$

where $k$ is a positive constant.

**My question**
What I would like to know is the physical justification for their claim.

**My thoughts**
There claim is somewhat surprising, since for sufficiently high insulation R, with r fixed, the speed of the impulse *decreases* (by L'Hospital) with *more* insulation.

---

*EDIT*: I received this email after contacting Brooks/Cole, the publisher of the textbook. The response didn't really help unfortunately.

> Hi Professor ...,
>
> I just heard back from the author regarding your query: “I can understand why Professor
> ... thinks this equation is counterintuitive, but it is in fact correct. I have been >trying to track down the source that I used in devising this problem, but unfortunately I >can’t seem to find it right now.” I will certainly let you know if he is able to track >down the source information. I’m sorry I can’t give you a more concrete answer at this >time. Best, ...
>
> [JIRA] (KYTS-1199) Content Feedback from Instructor for ISBN: 0495014281 Essential >Calculus: Early Transcendentals 1st edition.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the edit! I didn't realize I could use LaTeX or I would have.

Comment: Is this a coaxial lead or just some dielectric around some wire. Does that wording, "cable" or "insulation" come from that calculus book?

Comment: @Georg That is the exact wording from Stewart, using the terminology "metal cable" and "insulation".

Comment: Interesting, if we denote $x=\frac{r}{R}$ then $x^2\ln{x}$ has a minimum: $-\frac{1}{2e}$ at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$. It's a strange behavior in the physical sense, i think. It would be useful if you will add the text of the original problem.

Comment: One can make a lead for high frequency currents just by cladding a wire in a (thick) cover of some dielectric. This is more theoretical, I do not know about a practical use, but it is mentioned in textbooks. What kind of book is this "steward"? Calculus smells for a mathematics, maybe phsics author, which would excuse the unprofessional wording.

Comment: @MartinGales It is a standard introductory calculus text. James Stewart: Essential Calculus, Early Transcendentals. Section 3.7, pg 194, #44. A metal cable has radius $r$ and is covered by insulation, so that the distance from the center of the cable to the exterior of the insulation is $R$. The velocity $v$ of an electrical impulse in the cable is: $v = -c\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2 \ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)$.

Comment: My question regarding a physical explanation is different from the problem for students. Stewart is using this just an excuse to apply L'Hospitals rule. Specifically, students are asked to find and interpreting $\lim_{R\to r^+} v$ and $\lim_{r\to 0^+} v$, which does not require any physical explanation for the original equation.

Comment: Rises a question: What is meant by the electrical impulse in given case? Obviously not an electromagnetic wave whose speed depends only on the electrical and magnetic properties of the cable's insulator. The structure of the formula( $\ln\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)$ ) suggests that something moves perpendicular to the axis of the cable. A complete mystery!

Comment: Terms like ( ln(r/R) )  remind of formulas of coaxial cables. I'd post this question in some elctronics forum.

Answer (score 2):

I think i came to the origins of this equation.  In all likelihood, this equation describes not a speed of an electrical impulse but a direct current power transmitted via a superconducting coaxial cable.

A proof:

Consider a simple transmission  DC coaxial cable.  To eliminate the energy losses due to Joule heating in the cable, the inner(of radius $r$) and outer(of radius$R$) conductors are made from a superconductor. The inner conductor is insulated by a dielectric material. How much power can be transferred through the cable?

Let the maximum allowable magnetic field induction on the surface of the superconductor be $B_\text{max}$ and the maximum electric field in the insulating interlayer be $E_\text{max}$.  Let a current through the cable be $I$.

Then the following holds:

$$B_\text{max}=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\Rightarrow I=\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0}rB_\text{max}$$

Since we are dealing with superconductors they keep the potential on the surface(as well as the linear charge density λ) constant.

That means the following holds:

$$E_\text{max}=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0r}$$

The potential difference between inner and outer conductors:

$$U=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{r}^{R}\frac{dl}{l}=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\frac{R}{r}=rE_\text{max}\ln\frac{R}{r} $$

So, the power transmission:

$$P=UI=\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0}E_\text{max}B_\text{max}r^2\ln\frac{R}{r}$$

**This is the same function as in the question, only with different constant $k$**

To analyze the result let's introduce the ratio $x=\frac{R}{r}$:

$$P=UI=\frac{2\pi}{\mu_0}E_\text{max}B_\text{max}R^2\left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\right)$$

One can see that at $R=\text{const}$, $P$ as a function of $x$ has a maximum. This happens at $x=\sqrt{e}$

So the maximum power transfer in the DC superconducting transmission cable:

$$P_\text{max}=\frac{\pi}{\mu_0e}E_\text{max}B_\text{max}R^2$$